# vim-go: could not find 'gopls'

Tags: go, vim

After installing Plug 'fatih/vim-go' Plugin for golang i get few errors

steps:
When opening .go file with vim I get a error:

```
vim-go: could not find 'gopls' . Run :GoInstallBinaries to fix it
vim-go: could not determine appropriate working directory for go plus
```

When doing :GoInstallBinaries I get more errors like:

```
vim-go: guru not found. instaling golang.org..guru@master to folder C:\Users\*MYPC*\go\bin\
vim-go: Error instaling golang.org/x/tools/cmdfuru@master: The system cannot find the path specified.
vim-go: goplus not found. instaling golang.org..goplus@latest to folder C:\Users\*MYPC*\go\bin\
vim-go: Error instaling golang.org..goplus@latest: The system cannot find the path specified.
.
.
.
it does that 8 more times with godef,motion,errcheck,dlv,iferr,golint...
```

When i do :echo $PATH in Vim i have C:\Users*MYPC*\go\bin\

I am running gvim on Windows 10

golang in cmd or powershell work fine...

Comment: what is your actual username under `C:\Users`?

Comment: You first say _gopls_, and then you complain you can't find it?

Answer (score 3):

for mac was solved with

```
brew install gopls
```

Answer (score 1):

Just run `go get golang.org/x/tools/gopls@latest`, and problem solved!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: With go 1.18 and later, you actually need `go install golang.org/x/tools/gopls@latest' to get the actual binary into your go/bin directory. This is needed for vim to actually find/start it.

Answer (score 1):

In the `vim-go` setup instructions, there's a detail about running `:GoInstallBinaries` in vim after install. You probably missed it (I ran into this issue after I upgraded to a new go runtime)

Answer (score 1):

Answer for `WSL` (Windows subsystem for Linux):

I tried to installed `gopls` manually, running `go get golang.org/x/tools/gopls@latest` but I was getting the following error:

```
XXXX@XXXX:~$ go get golang.org/x/tools/gopls@latest
go: can only use path@version syntax with 'go get' and 'go install' in module-aware mode
```

Changing the Go mode fixed the problem at this stage `GO111MODULE=on`, then I could run

```
go install golang.org/x/tools/gopls@latest
```

However, later on, when `vim-go` was trying to install the missing packages after running `GoInstallBinaries` I was getting errors that I couldn't use versions with `go install`. So what I did was reinstall Go (the latest version) on the system using these [instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/755392/1578758). After doing that, `vim-go` was able to install the packages. I hope this answer saves time for future `vim-go` enthusiasts.